# Why does shooting a handgun accelerate a bullet to deadly speed without injuring the gun user's hand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, estimation

Momentum is defined by the product of mass and velocity. Now a projectile out of a gun has to have high velocity to penetrate a human body, as its mass isn't significant. But to reach this velocity, due to inertia/the law of energy conservation, momentum on both sides is to be equal. As there is strong negative acceleration in the opposite direction of the bullet, it should result in a strong force in the opposite direction of the bullet ($F = m*a $).

Therefore I wonder why shooting a bullet with a handgun is not ripping your hand apart.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this interesting conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87693/discussion-on-question-by-zurechtweiser-why-does-shooting-a-handgun-produce-a-bu). Please use comments only to suggest improvements to the question or request clarification from the asker.

Comment: Piercing a human doesn't require as much energy as you might think. It's about pressure. Imagine a knife, or a needle. A bullet has a small area so doesn't need a lot of energy to pierce. Imagine holding a stick the diameter of a bullet in place of the gun and having someone push a leg of lamb onto it. How hard would you need to brace in order for the stick to pierce the meat?

Answer (score 43):

Firstly, some guns do give quite a kick!  So the effect you are thinking of is real.

However, conservation of momentum means that $m_\text{bullet} \cdot v_\text{bullet} = m_\text{gun} \cdot v_\text{gun}$.  So the bullet's velocity is greater than that of the gun by a ratio of $\frac{m_\text{gun}}{m_\text{bullet}}$.  Then energy is distributed in the same ratio because while energy scales as velocity squared, it also scales with the mass.  So, it is useful for the gun to be heavy and/or for it to have a spring-loaded mechanism to slowly distribute the kick to your hand and body.

Comment: Spot on about the mass of the gun.  by the way, the spring loaded mechanism that dampens recoil is typically the action of a semi-automatic of automatic firearm.  The purpose of that action isn't to dampen recoil, but rather to eject the spent cartridge and chamber the next cartridge.  However, in using recoil energy to reload the weapon, it does indeed dampen recoil.  However, there is a mechanism on firearms that is specifically designed to dampen recoil: The muzzle brake, which directs some of the propellant gasses backwards and thereby counters some of the force of recoil.

Comment: @WayneConrad It may soak up energy, but it cannot soak up momentum.

Comment: Does the weight of the gun actually matter? If the gun were lighter or heavier _(but with the same shape)_, wouldn't it still apply the same overall force to the same area of the hand?  What seems important is that the impact area is much larger than the bullet's, and the force is dampened so the energy gets dispersed more slowly.

Comment: @Blue - Yeah, after it overcomes the inertia of the gun and other losses due to distortions. It will still apply the same overall force *to the weapon* which is what then, if designed right, correctly transfers the energy to your body mercifully, instead of you ending up pointing it at your forehead after every discharge.

Comment: @blue - There used to be rifles that were like 8' long. You couldn't aim the thing and it was hard to walk around with. So they cut 2~3' off. Now no one wants to fire it. Even though the barrel is shorter and it's likely not utilizing all the propellant in the cartage, because that it's lighter its recoil is worse. Much, much worse...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The weight of the weapon plays a huge part.

Comment: @Yakk - "It may soak up energy, but it cannot soak up momentum." It doesn't need to. By extending the recoil absorption over a longer distance, and therefor longer time, it reduces the peak recoil force on the shooter, and that is an important part of perceived recoil.

Comment: @WayneConrad is correct, although I'd like to add the effect of the recoil spring in most short recoil operation handguns is huge on felt recoil. Many race shooters tune their recoil springs, and if done correctly and to the user's preference, can almost completely eliminate felt recoil. Many people use custom aftermarket guide rods and recoil springs for this purpose. They are often rated by poundage, and are tuned to reduce the amount of recoil transferred to the action to just the amount needed to cycle it, and nothing more transferred to the user.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The weight of a gun matters a lot in many ways. All one has to do is fire similar guns that have very different weights (this is not hard to find). Heavier guns can be harder to hold and move quickly, but are much more stable with less recoil.

Comment: @Mazura - I'm going to call you on your 8' / 5' example. I'm very, very dubious. If you can provide a specific example, I'll change my tune, but not until.

Comment: "Recoil in the 6.5 lb. carbines was pretty grim." – [STEYR M95 8X56R](https://www.buymilsurp.com/rifle-parts-accessories-steyr-m95-8x56r-c-3548_2083.html) - The weight of an original [Mannlicher M1895](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1895) was 8.3 lb. Shortened - and therefore almost two whole pounds less out of eight - and with a more capable cartridge, yeah it sucks. We fire this once a year per man, if that, just to remember how bad it sucks.

Comment: @Blue - I'm told M60s just kinda shake. There's springs and stuff in there, but it also happens to weigh in at well over 20 pounds. (I'm glad you called me out - "grim"' was actually an anecdote of my father's, which TIL ;) I'm surprised this isn't intuitive of a [door gunner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/202233/23785), but perhaps that's why ;p - you haven't fired a lot of different types of (old, recoil system-less) rifles have you?

Comment: The shorter you make the barrel, the less force gets transmitted back to the weapon, this is true. The problem is what happens immediately after it combusts in the chamber. If it were hydraulics, the gun is bigger than the bullet: everything's fine. If both your 'cylinders' are the same size, you still get an equal and opposite reaction, only this time there's a tiny pipe stuck in your hand.

Comment: Compared to the both nearly 9 pound 7.62x54mmR Nagant and .30-06 Springfield rifles we have (either of which I'd fire all day - the former preferably), we might as well toss this 6 pound 8x56mmR Styre in the river. I guess unless you're a physicist, looking at the ballistic data for these cartridges  (they're *basically* negligible) wouldn't tell you all that. Looking at the weight of the weapon would (assuming no recoil system).

Comment: @WayneConrad There are other systems specifically designed to dampen recoil.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoil_buffer

Comment: Buffers are why we can't just look at the cartridges, unless we're firing ancient bolt-action rifles. With all other things being equal (all rifles share the same basic silhouette) WEIGHT is all that's left when considering felt recoil. @WhatRoughBeast - this is getting out of hand, am I done here yet? ;p

Comment: @Mazura - Sorry, but you seem to have misunderstood. What firearm was 8 feet long, cut down to 5? And yes, the M60 was a joy to fire, if not to carry. I've gone through 5000 rounds in a night from a modified shoulder position. There's an assault position (for grunts) which involves resting the butt plate on the upper thigh just below the groin. No problem. I qualified with the M14, and it turns out I have a tender shoulder even with the effects of a semiautomatic mechanism, so I'm a really big fan of recoil systems, and glad I never had to deal with bolt-action rifles bigger than a .22.

Comment: The ratios are about right but the numbers are a bit overzealous (by about twice: **it went from 4.25 feet to 3.25 feet, losing one pound**). "Weight: 7.4 lbs (3.36 kg) (short rifle), 8.4 lbs (3.8 kg) (long rifle). Length: 39 in (100 cm) (short rifle), 50.1 in (127.2 cm) (long rifle). Barrel length: 19 in (48 cm) (short rifle), 30.1 in (76.5 cm) (long rifle)" [imfdb.org](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Steyr_Mannlicher_M1895) - Saying they basically cut the barrel in half wouldn't be that far off.

Comment: @Mazura If I were to assume an elastic situation where no energy is dissipated/lost to environment what will reduce the force/impact on human ? (In an inelastic situation, energy will be lost to the environment much better in a heavier gun, if I am correct )

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast how does the mass affect recoil other than rotation wise(moment of inertia will be lower for smaller gun so it rotates more) . But if a small force is applied for a long time and linear momentum is independent of mass of gun, then how does more mass cause less recoil damage to body in case of pure translation motion?

Comment: @Aurelius - " recoil damage" is a function of peak force, not so much of total impulse. As an example, a car hitting you at 5 mph will do little damage besides possibly knocking you down. If it happens 100 tmies, it will apply as much energy to your body as a single impact at 50 mph, and that is a much different proposition.

Answer (score 30):

The handgun is braced with a large surface area of the hand, and the palm and entire hand are robust; the result is that the hand, or hand and arm, or hand and upper body are sharply displaced as a whole before the motion is damped by the rest of the body.

Some details of recoil are discussed [here](https://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2012/ARL-CR-692.pdf). The recoil of rifles, which are generally more powerful, braced near the shoulder, and operated near the face, can easily cause a broken collarbone, torn rotator cuff, black eye, and/or detached retina.

Thus, whether injury occurs depends on the stress induced in vivo from the acceleration of the brace position vs. the relative strength of the nearby organs.

Comment: The hand (and wrist, forearm, &c) also has many flexible muscles and joints, which act as shock absorbers.  Not just when firing a pistol: think of hitting something with your fist.

Comment: If the gun weighed as much (very important) as the projectile, and was as small (also important), it would. We have an ancient Styre rifle that was shortened at some point, vastly reducing it's weight. Its recoil went from being described as 'unpleasant' to 'grim'.

Comment: The mass of the firearm also plays a significant role.

Comment: Occasionally, beginning rifle shooters attempt to "deal with" the recoil by bracing their shooting shoulder against a good stout tree. They generally only try that once.

Answer (score 27):

> Therefore I wonder why shooting a bullet with a handgun is not ripping your hand apart.

Because the mass of the handgun is greater than the mass of the bullet, and because the energy transferred from the gun to your hand is distributed across the surface of the pistol grip.

One of the more interesting things I heard on a trip to Williamsburg Virginia (which is period of ~1776; American Revolution) was the question of how much the muskets weighed. The historical figure answered (I don't recall the weight) and the questioner said in a surprised voice, "That's basically the same that guns weigh today!"

"Yes," replied this historical figure, "because the physics hasn't changed. They *could* make rifles lighter today, but they don't because the recoil would be worse."

There are other things put in modern pistols to reduce recoil like springs and discharge, but since you tagged it "Newtonian physics" I expect your are less interested in those things.

Comment: This answer covers it best. If you had a 'bullet trap' of the same weight as the gun, which decelerated the bullet over an equally long trajectory as it was fired, catching a bullet using this device would be no harder than firing it. Catching a bullet with just the mass of skin in front of it, over the thickness of said skin, generally doesn't work for anything but bb's.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn a bulletproof vest is one example of "bullet trap"

Comment: Re "They could make rifles lighter today...", they do.  Compare the weight of an M14 to the M16, for instance.  Or for pistols, the .45 caliber Colt M1911 weighs 1100 g, the comparable Glock .45 845 g.  (Other Glock models weigh even less.)

Comment: @Zurechtweiser Sorry, that's what I saw and assumed you did it.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, I was indoor shooting once and was allowed to hold a ceramic .45 pistol about ten years ago, and it was *strangely light.* My (law enforcement) friend shot it and almost lost her grip on it when she fired it (because of the low weight) - it may have been a Glock I don't recall.  In general though, there are fewer people that can handle a very low weight high power pistol in my opinion.

Comment: Do modern rifles have a different distribution of mass? If you took a hypothetical light modern rifle and added weight to the stock to bring the total mass back up to about the weight of a musket, it seems like you'd keep the recoil benefits of the heavier weapon but also get some of the handling benefits of a lighter weapon by having the mass exert a smaller lever moment.

Comment: @jamesqf: M16 is lighter, but it also shoots rounds that are roughly half the mass.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The distribution of the weight does matter, as you suggest, but the weight itself is also important. Obviously in armed combat against other humans, there is plenty of time spent marching, running, etc., where the absolute weight of all the gear is a significant factor. For hunting, weight is also a factor. And merely aiming a heavier firearm in situations where you can't rest it on something can tire the arms more quickly and lead to shaking muscles, so there's a tradeoff.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There's also a tradeoff of muzzle control vs. handling as mass is moved forward or back in a rifle.  More forward weight keeps the muzzle more stable, but increases the polar moment of inertia when moving the gun around, and vice versa.

Comment: "the recoil would be worse" That's why standard issue isn't the carbine version. Paratroopers and other elite units often prefer the shorter carbine (because they have an objective to accomplish, not a crate of ammo to run through before they can take lunch). However sore their shoulders are at the end of the day just lets them know they're still alive.

Answer (score 7):

By holding the gun firmly and taking a proper firing pose, you arrange it so that the momentum is passed to your entire body as a whole or a large enough part of it. Your body is much heavier than a bullet, so the speed it gets from the shot is very small and easily countered by muscles and joints.

If you don't take a proper pose or don't hold the gun properly, you may fail to steady it against the knockback or the momentum could otherwise be passed only to a small part of the body, resulting in injury.

Answer (score 1):

Lets nail down some figures with a random choice of compatible equipment with specs publicly available.

Gun https://us.glock.com/products/G19
Gun Weight with empty magazine 670 g | 23.63 oz
Barrel Length 102 mm | 4.02 inch (slightly less than ammo test, so time under acceleration is slightly less)

Ammunition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9%C3%9719mm_Parabellum
Bullet mass 8.04 g (124 gr)     Federal FMJ
Bullet velocity 1,150 ft/s (350 m/s) @ 118mm (4.65") barrel length, 0.00067s 
Bullet energy 364 ft⋅lbf (494 J)

We could set this up as a conservation of energy problem, and that would be a reasonable approximation with a satisfying answer.
The time under acceleration is very short(0.00067s). (anything less than 0.01s feels instantaneous)
The gun weighs a lot (83 times) more than the bullet.
It is coupled to a human that weighs very much more.(180lb = 10155 times)
It is coupled over a large, soft, energy absorbing surface(hand).
The recoil is transmitted through several relatively massive energy absorbing tendons, tensed muscles, bones, flexed joints, fat, fluids, which redirect the recoil into countless vectors.

Where is the point of impact between gun and bullet?  How does the gun impart force to the bullet and the bullet impart equal and opposite force to the gun?    Well that doesn't really happen.  It isn't a collision.
Only the timing is similar to a collision because both gun and bullet are accelerated in opposite directions by expanding gasses with same T0.
But is energy imparted equally?  The center of those gasses is itself being accelerated away from the gun.  Barrel friction counteracts recoil.  You may be mistaken in part of your premise "momentum on both sides is to be equal".

Comment: gasses -> gases

Comment: @FaheemMitha In British English, and possibly all others except US English (where it is no longer the common variation), [gasses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gasses) is correct.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Wow, I don't think I've come across that variant before. Or if I have, I don't remember it.

Comment: How much the human weights is quite irrelevant: When the bullet leaves the gun, the gun has moved back by $102mm/83 = 1.2mm$ and is moving at a speed of $350\frac{m}{s}/83 = 4.2\frac{m}{s} = 15\frac{km}{h}$. The gun subsequently basically crashes into the human at that speed: The tiny translation of $1.2mm$ is simply not enough to transmit any relevant forces.

Comment: That said, if you half the weight of the gun, you get it crashing into the user at twice the speed, i.e. $30\frac{km}{h}$, which is definitely not fun.

Comment: lets -> let's = "let us". "Lets" without an apostrophe is synonymous with "allows". As in, "Stack Exchange lets you comment if you have enough rep". We wouldn't say "Allows nail down some figures...", and we would say "Let us nail down some figures..."

Comment: @cmaster I was allowed to fire an 8 gauge trumpet barrelled goose gun when I was 11 years old.  I assure you, my weight was quite relevant.  It knocked me on my but.  Upper body weight is more significant, but harder to quantify.  Also, recoil is not simply translation.  Guns can rotate sharply breaking wrists.  That is why some have compensation ports.

Comment: @slomobile Yes, your body weight is very relevant in the collision between moving gun and body. My point was, that this collision does not happen until *after the shot has been fired*. The moment that you have relevant forces between body and gun, the bullet is already far, far away. As such, a large body weight, or a good contact between body and gun, cannot influence the amount of energy in the recoil. When the gun crashes into your body, you must absorb the entire kinetic energy that the gun gained when it was fired.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming impulse invariance, roughly the same amount of momentum is transferred to the shooter and the bullet and ultimately the target.  However, if momentum was the only lethal element of a bullet, there would not be such a thing as a bullet-proof vest since a bullet-proof vest cannot keep momentum off the target (you'd need a ground-mounted shield for that).  It can, however, absorb and disperse energy which, as opposed to momentum, grows with the square of the speed of moving mass.  A bullet will often not transfer all of its energy to the target unless it gets stuck and will rather work by inflicting deadly injury, but there are some that are designed to stop and/or disperse on entry, like hollow point bullets.  Those tend to be much more deadly than an ordinary bullet even when not hitting vital parts of the body.

So the basic point is that a pistol has more mass than the bullet, so while they share momentum equally (at least when discounting what exhaust fumes may do), they don't receive equal amounts of energy.

Note that shoulder-held rocket launchers are built in a way where the exhaust fumes (which continue accelerating the rocket via conservation of momentum) can leave the launcher at its back, thus minimizing the amount of momentum transferred to the operator (naturally, the place behind someone with a rocket launcher is a very bad place to be as opposed to being behind a gunner).  Since it is the pressure of the propellant explosion rather than the momentum of something leaving the bullet, this kind of mechanism is not feasible with a gun to a good degree.