# Why is throwing a bullet by hands not effective as using a gun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, relative-motion

The bullet when fired applies equal and opposite force to the Gun, (Newton's 3rd law)
Thus to keep the gun stable we apply some force which should be equal to the force applied by the bullet.
If we are humans are able to apply such force then why is throwing the bullet not effective as using a gun

I know Iam completely wrong here but I want to know the reason still

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for an answer with estimated calculations, but think of conservation of momentum, mass*velocity, small bullet goes fast through the air, but much larger gun recoils with human arm attached to human body, standing on the ground. And people don't go flying when shot like in the movies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shooting a handgun accelerate a bullet to deadly speed without injuring the gun user's hand?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451025/)

Comment: To clarify the later part of the question, shock absorption/ dampening by different specialized tissues has nothing much to do with application of force. An average healthy person should be able to survive the shock of jumping off a 2 meter wall or even a 1 story building but it's nearly impossible to jump that high.